# why my Python Django urls is not working?

Tags: django, django-urls

I am working on a python django website and my urls are not working properly. I have included my urls.py and the nav links which are the same on each page.

Urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views        
        
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('products/', views.products, name='products'),
    path('customer/<str:pk_test>/', views.customer, name="customer"),
]
```

navbar.html:

```
{% load static %}
        
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}">
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
         <ul class="navbar-nav">
           <li class="nav-item active">
             <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Dashboard</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'products' %}">Products</a>
           </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Please identify the issue. What bug you're receiving? or the expected output and what you're currently seeing?

Comment: In SO, Minimum Explanation, Code Sample, and output of the code are required in order to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

With minimum information provided, I can come to understand that you facing problem to visit another link or url using your navbar despite providing correct information. If that is the case, I think this can solve your issue.

Check your class nav-link :

`<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'products' %}">Products</a>`

You must also provide the namespace of your application from the settings urls.py like this:

```
`<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'app_namespace:products' %}">Products</a>`
```

This is the reference from documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Comment: Thanks, brother. I am new to the stack overflow. I will try my best to maintain the stack overflow standard next time.